# Why do we need to pass a resource layout to a custom adapter in constructor?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am curious to know this as I am not able to find it in internet.

I am creating a custom list adapter. In this adapter there is a getView method which I am overriding. In this method I inflate the row layout which I pick from layout folder.

In this case I should not need to pass the same row layout as a constructor to the adapter, which is not allowed.

Please answer.

Regards
Utsav.

Comment: what's exactly your doubt ?

Comment: Why the code redundancy?

Comment: in your `getView` use `final View inflatedOrRecycledView = super.getView(....);`  it should always be not null ... edit: and yes, as Konstantins Bogdanovs wrote ... why you need an ArrayAdapter

Comment: You can just extend BaseAdapter but not ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Selvin This makes sense

Comment: but still i would go for own BaseAdapter implementation https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/bb4f8aebb129f1db9420

Comment: can you tell the difference that I will achieve by using BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter? I am a bit new here.

Comment: most programmers are not using all those methods from ArrayAdapter (like sort, add, addAll, all filtering stuff) ... so BaseAdapter is a better choice as it's less bloated just compare [ArrayAdapter source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) with [my MinimalArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/bb4f8aebb129f1db9420) which in most cases have enogh functionallity

Comment: anyway check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/96d1cce71ba3bfaf5ab5)

Answer (score 1):

you can safely ignore it by overriding the constructor, like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        super(context, 0);
    }
}
```

**edit:**

That exists for cases that you're not creating a custom adapter, e.g. `new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.item);`

This adapter would write the value of `to string()` of its data items to `TextView` with ID `android.R.id.text1` inside that layout.

Comment: This works but it still does not answer as to why we would need that. Is there a scenario you can point ?

Comment: '0' is just because the super class class demands that we pass an integer, it could have been '-100' or 'new Random().nextInt()' it makes no difference. I edited the answer with a real world use case